# How can I see the most voted comment (site-wide)?

Tags: discussion

I'm just curious about what's the most upvoted comment (site-wide).

Is there a way we could see that? Maybe a short list (up to 10) of the most voted comments as we can see the [most voted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) (a slight difference here is that for questions the downvotes count too, in a negative way).

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/477022/top-comment-votes-again

Comment: @honk thanks :) But I'm asking this **site-wide**, not only _my comments_.

Comment: @lealceldeiro: Sorry, I missed that. It's far too hot here for my brain to work properly...

Comment: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/8132455), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/17695741), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/5395836), and [the rest](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882761/top-comments).

Comment: @wim yes, that's the query posted in the accepted answer :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no ways to search comments using the built-in tools, but using SEDE, it's very easy.

You can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882761/top-comments) to order comments by score

```
SELECT TOP 100 Id As [Comment Link], Score, Text, UserDisplayName
FROM Comments
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

Comment: Does it include Meta comments?

Comment: Nope, but you can switch the site to meta for meta comments. Just copy-paste the query there.

Comment: @ManojKumar, as Erik von Asmuth said: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/882761/top-comments